# Using Ord to create and compare empty lists

Tags: haskell, empty-list, ord

I am trying to create an empty list then confirm that it is empty so I can later on insert elements into it.

I tried to simply assign the function to an empty list but when i try to confirm that it is empty I get an Non-exhaustive patterns in function exception.

Here is what I have so far.

```hs
emptyList::Ord a => [(a,b)]
emptyList = []

isEmpty::Ord a => [(a,b)] -> Bool
isEmpty[(a,b)] = null [undefined, undefined]
```

I am trying to get something like 

`isEmpty emptyList 
True`

I guess my question here is that, how can I confirm that the list is empty based on the given type?

Comment: Well you wrote `[(a,b)]` as pattern. This means it will only match for lists that contain exactly *one* element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing the type (`[(a,b)]`) with the patterns. In your `isEmpty` function, you write:

```
isEmpty::Ord a => [(a,b)] -> Bool
isEmpty [(a,b)] = null [undefined, undefined]
```

But this does not mean that you are going to match lists of *type* `[(a,b)]`. You already said that in your type signature. Your `[(a,b)]` in the second line, means you define a pattern. The pattern sayd that you are only matching lists that contain *exactly* one element: a 2-tuple, with `a` the first item of that tuple, and `b` the second item of that tuple.

If you then pass it an empty list, or a list with two or more elements, then the pattern will not match, and hence it will raise an error.

If you want to match *any* list, you can simply use a variable:

```
isEmpty :: Ord a => [(a,b)] -> Bool
isEmpty ls = null ls
```

here `isEmpty` thus will call `null` with that variable. We can perform an *η-reduction* here, and write:

```
isEmpty :: Ord a => [(a,b)] -> Bool
isEmpty = null
```

There is no need at all, to restrict ourselves to only lists with 2-tuples where the first item of these tuples has a type that is a member of the `Ord` typeclass however, we can let this work with any list. So we can generalize the type to:

```
isEmpty :: [a] -> Bool
isEmpty = null
```

In fact `null` can operate over any `Foldable`, since it has type [**`null :: Foldable f => f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#null).

Given the above function defintion, there is no need to implement your own `isEmpty`, you can simply call `null emptyList`.

Comment: thank you very much your explanation was most helpful, I totally misunderstood the concept of using variables in these functions. Thanks.